# Tableau: Filter Using an Aggregate

Tags: filter, aggregate, tableau-api, dashboard

Without having access to edit the database or perform an ETL, I would like to create a filter for a sheet that evaluates the sum of widget_1 by team versus total widget production and filter to only show teams with all sales in widget_1.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU5dG.png)

How can I do this at the sheet level versus at the ETL level?

Comment: can you attach the sheet?

Comment: what is the real logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this ...

1. Create a calculated field (I called it LOD) that does this:

   {FIXED [Team] : if sum([Widget 2]) = 0 then sum([Widget 1]) else NULL end}
2. Create a calculated field (I called it FILTER) that does this:

   sum([LOD]) = sum([Widget 1])

Drag FILTER to the filter shelf and select True only

That should work :)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! Worked Perfect! I just read a Tableau page to figure out the logic of your statement. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_filters.htm This helped me understand the difference between the different filter types and put it into SQL terms.

Comment: No worries, let me know if you have any questions.  it's basically like doing a separate query and then comparing your existing data to the new separate data.